# How to remove the last character of a macro using a regex (expl3)?

Tags: macros, expl3, l3regex

I'm trying to remove the `%` sign that I added to a macro that stores in sequences to prevent `(^M/ASCII-Return)` that adds `TeX` when processing the argument using `\scantokens`.

Everything is perfect, but, by using `\meaning` I would like to remove the `%` sign I added at the end. 
With my example the output is:

```
Using \verb+\Scontents+ command,verbatim support, using balanced
braces, save in seq nospaceafter with index $1$.No space after close
:)%
```

and what I want is:

```
Using \verb+\Scontents+ command,verbatim support, using balanced
braces, save in seq nospaceafter with index $1$.No space after close
:)
```

This is my example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { scontents }
  {
    store-cmd .tl_set:N  = \l__scontents_name_seq_cmd_tl,
    store-cmd .initial:n = contents,
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__scontents_append_contents:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cF { g__scontents_seq_name_#1_seq }
      { \seq_new:c { g__scontents_seq_name_#1_seq } }
    \seq_gput_right:cn { g__scontents_seq_name_#1_seq } {#2}
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__scontents_getfrom_seq:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_item:cn { g__scontents_seq_name_#2_seq } {#1}
  }
\exp_args_generate:n { Vx }
% stored
\ProvideDocumentCommand{ \Scontents }{ O{} +v }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \IfNoValueF {#1} { \keys_set_known:nn { scontents } {#1} }
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#2}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \^^M } { \^^J } \l_tmpa_tl
    \exp_args:NVx \__scontents_append_contents:nn \l__scontents_name_seq_cmd_tl
      { \exp_not:N \tex_scantokens:D { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl \c_percent_str} }
    \group_end:
  }
% get
\ProvideDocumentCommand{ \getstored } { O{1} m }
  { 
    \__scontents_getfrom_seq:nn {#1} {#2} 
  }

% meaning
\ProvideDocumentCommand{ \meaningsc } { O{1} m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \__scontents_getfrom_seq:nn {#1} {#2} }
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { ^ \c{tex_scantokens:D} \cB. (\c[^BE].*) \cE. } { \1 } \l_tmpb_tl
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \v{1,} } { } \l_tmpb_tl
    % this not work
    \tl_reverse:N \l_tmpb_tl % reverse
    \tl_remove_once:Nn \l_tmpb_tl { \c_percent_str } % remove 
    \tl_reverse:N \l_tmpb_tl % reverse
    \ttfamily
    \cs_replacement_spec:N \l_tmpb_tl
    \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\Scontents[store-cmd=nospaceafter]{Using \verb+\Scontents+ command, 
verbatim support, using balanced braces, save in seq nospaceafter with index $1$.

No space after close :)}

\Scontents[store-cmd=nospaceafter]|Using \verb+\Scontents+ command, 
delimited by tbar, save in seq nospaceafter with index $2$. end by \verb+%+
\begin{verbatim*}
      verbatim environment
      with unbalanced } braces } 
\end{verbatim*}
No space after close, one percent at end of line%|

\noindent\hrulefill

XX\getstored[1]{nospaceafter}.No space after :) YY\par

\noindent\hrulefill

XX\getstored[2]{nospaceafter}.No space after :) YY

\noindent\hrulefill

\meaningsc[1]{nospaceafter}

\noindent\hrulefill

\meaningsc[2]{nospaceafter}

\end{document}
```

I tried to use `\tl_reverse:N` and it doesn't work, I think maybe it can be done with some `regex` (I'm not sure about this).

Saludos

Comment: With regex perhaps match `(.*?).$` and replace by `\1`. It will do a lazy matching of anything, any number of times, plus another anything followed by the end of the string (not tested). To remove only a percent, perhaps `(.*?)\%?$`...

Comment: I'm still confused about your aim. But why not add `\prg_do_nothing:` instead of `\c_percent_str`?

Comment: I use `%` to avoid the invisible space added when running `\getstored`...I haven't tried using `\prg_do_nothing:`, I know that if I use `\relax` I get the same effect, but still, it shouldn't be shown when using `\meaningsc` and I'd have to remove it ...a thousand apologies if I've explained myself incorrectly